# What's ideal debugging setup? window placement etc

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, netbeans

I am interested in knowing Debugging setup that'll allow a programmer to be most productive. Assuming knowledge about debugging in general.
I am mainly interested in knowing how and where you place different windows like the variables window, code window, the stack. Also possibly the relative size of different windows.

I'd prefer if there are screenshots attached and a description of why the setup works for you or one that is efficient.

I mainly use Eclipse and Netbeans.

Answer (score 3):

Most productive? That's going to vary greatly from person to person. You shouldn't focus on what works best for other people or details like precise window placement... figure out what works best for you with some trial and error.

For me, multiple monitors are important. I keep code and tools (Eclipse, SQL manager, etc) open on one, and use the other for the console and the running program (whatever it may be: website, windowed application, etc).

Comment: Another +1 for multiple monitors.  Otherwise, here's a screenshot of my setup: http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/1671/screenxc.png

Answer (score 2):

First you have to know how to use the debugger really well and then after that the placement of windows is just frivolous detail, for the most part. It will just fall into place without having to mimic other people's comfort level with the tools.

It sounds like you're looking for a static setup but likely you will show/hide windows depending on what you're debugging and size them to different situations. At least that's what I do. So I would post many screenshots and they'd all look different.

> "*I'd prefer if there are screenshots attached and a description of why **the setup works for you**.* "

You're exactly right knowing it works for the other person.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said, one thing that I do with respect to variable windows - Visual Studio gives you 4 different watch windows. I usually put them all into a single tabbed window, and each tab will represent a different programming context. For example, tab 1 will list variables that I usually need to look at when dealing with area A, tab 2 has variables for area B and so on.

Doing this, I find that the watch windows don't get over cluttered and I spend less time setting up variables